# Drain snake cable fell out of spinner

Tags: plumbing

I have a drain snake and the cable "fell out" of the container. I'm not sure if this means it is broken or if there is a way to reconnect it and push it back in.

It is not an electric one , just a simple plastic manual old drain snake

Comment: Bases on the title, I thought you lost the snake in the toilet, and it went down the pipe.  I shed a tear for you.  Then I read the full question and realized it was nothing so dramatic.  Whew!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snake is designed to be removable. Just insert the tail end into the opening and carefully push the snake back into the container. Use a twisting motion for the first foot or so to help the snake coil up in the container instead of wadding into a bunch.

You may need to remove the locking thumbscrew entirely to allow the tail end of the snake to slide past.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a small one like this [hand snake](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Plumb-Craft-Titan-Drain-Auger/15388949?action=product_interest&action_type=title&item_id=15388949&placement_id=irs-106-t1&strategy=PWVAV&visitor_id&category=&client_guid=4802a9b4-5f2a-4fbc-9c4b-340dc339877f&customer_id_enc&config_id=106&parent_item_id=36883566&parent_anchor_item_id=36883566&guid=21913227-fba7-4455-ae07-1dc07f6a0e01&bucket_id=irsbucketdefault&beacon_version=1.0.1&findingMethod=p13n) some have a clip on the inside to anchor the end. If you cannot open it up to get to a clip just shove it back in. Make sure to lock the snake when spinning so it doesn’t get all twisted.